# In BASH, How do i connect to local system DB2 or MySQL to do a simple query?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash, fedora

Is there any way to connect to the local system (localhost) using BASH. To do simple query to one table?

e.g: select *from mydb1.table1 > and read all the columns to process in BASH

```
$ mysql --skip-column-names --user=root my -e "select *from aanspreektitels"
+------------+----+------------------+----+
|         M. |  1 |         Monsieur | FR |
|       Mme. |  2 |           Madame | FR |
|      Mlle. |  3 |     Mademoiselle | FR |
|       Dhr. |  4 |     Geachte heer | NL |
|      Mevr. |  5 |  Geachte mevrouw | NL |
|     Juffr. |  6 | Geachte juffrouw | NL |
| A l'attent |  8 |    A l'attent du | FR |
|       Tav. |  9 |             Tav. | NL |
|       Miss | 10 |      Dear Misses | EN |
|       Frau | 11 |    Geehrter Frau | DE |
|       Herr | 12 |    Geehrter Herr | DE |
|    Zum der | 13 |          Zum der | DE |
|        Sir | 14 |         Dear Sir | EN |
|          A | 15 |                A | DE |
+------------+----+------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -e "select * from mydb1.table1"
```

Comment: +1 1) ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
2) ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'my' 3) After that two error and by adding extra `--skip-column-names --user=root my` worked.

Answer (score 0):

:mysql --skip-column-names -uname -ppwd dbname -B -e "$sqlstat" > $tmpfile